# Export HTML table to Excel through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel, export-to-excel

I am trying to export a HTML table to Excel with JS. I know that there are packages for this, however I am in an environment where I cannot use them.

The issue I run into is that Excel applies its own formating rules to the table, which I do not want. I have each cell's formating (of the format # ###.0% for example), decimal and thousand separator, but have yet to achieve any success.

For example, including the formating in the table like `"<td style='mso-number-format:" + format + "'>" + value + "</td>")` has not worked for me.

The code I'm using to export the table is

```
var BOM = '<html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>',
  data = BOM + "<H1>" + (exportReportTitle || "Rapport") + "</H1>\n" + "<h2>" + (chartTitle || "") + "</h2><br>" + subtitle + "<br>" + dataString + "<br>" + footnote + "<br><br>" + metaData,
  blob = new Blob([data], {
    //type: "application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8"
    type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
  });
saveAs(blob, fileName)
```

Where dataString is a normal HTML table. I've also tried to enclose the table in `<pre>` tags, and this works to some extent, but not for percentages (Excel still applies its auto percentage formating).